# Problema al cerrar sesión en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de cerrar sesión luego de logearme, es decir, que al darle a `salir`, destruir la sesión y evitar que el usuario se regrese en la página y vuelva a entrar sin iniciar sesión. Pero no funciona lo que realizo.

Cuando el usuario se va a logear, ingresa sus datos y son procesados de la siguiente manera:

```php
if(isset($_POST['usuario']))
        {
            $datosController = array(
                "usuario" => $_POST['usuario'],
                "password" => $_POST['pass']
            );

            $respuesta = Datos::ingresoUsuarioModel($datosController);

            if($respuesta['usuario'] == $_POST['usuario'] && $respuesta['password'] == $_POST['pass'])
            {

                session_start();

                $_SESSION = array(
                    "validar" => true,
                    "check" => $respuesta['tipo_usuario']
                );

                header("location:views/producto.php");
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:index.php?action=fallo");
            }
        }
```

En la pagina "producto", la cual es la que ingresa luego de logear, tengo lo siguiente:

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['validar']))
    {

        header("location:../");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Producto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>producto</h2>

    <a href="salir.php">Salir</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Y luego al darle a "salir", tengo lo siguiente:

```php
<?php 
    session_start();

    $_SESSION = array();

    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }

    session_destroy();


    header("location:../");

?>
```

Pero luego de darle a salir, no cierra la sesión como debería ya que si me devuelvo en el navegador, puedo ingresar a la página "producto" otra vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré una solución, había un problema en la condición de la variable de sesión `$_SESSION` en la página del "producto".

- Código del ejemplo:

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['validar']))
    {

        header("location:../");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Producto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>producto</h2>

    <a href="salir.php">Salir</a>
</body>
</html>
```

- Lo sustituí por lo siguiente:

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    $validado = $_SESSION["validar"] ?? false;

    if (!$validado) 
    {
        header("location:../");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Producto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>producto</h2>

    <a href="salir.php">Salir</a>
</body>
</html>
```